# Detect if Java is in protected mode, and what permissions Java has

Tags: java, permissions, protected

I need a way of detecting whether or not Java is in Protected mode, and what permissions Java has. It would be awesome if I could get this in C#, but my guess is that it would be easiest in Java (if that is the case, any idea on how to link it into a Visual Studio project?) Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by a "protected mode"? Are you talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode I haven't heard anyone use this term since the '80s.

Comment: no, i want to see if java has permission to write/read/delete files to the local file system. i believe this is associated with the integrity level that a program is running at, but not entirely sure

Comment: That would be the security manager's decision. You could also try `new File(".").list()` and see if it throws `SecurityException` or not...

Comment: The SecurityManager can selectively allow access to specific files or directories. You need to have a clearer idea of what it is you are trying to do,.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking whether there is an active security manager? Call `System.getSecurityManager()` and see if it returns null.